# Displaying json with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need for a project to use Json to display a picture wall with some special effects. I decided to use [Classier Json](http://www.thomasfrank.se/classier_json.html) to easily create classes. I'm new to json ad i don't know how to display the content of my objects.
Here is my code :

```
// RANGES - MOSAIC

// Main class
Image=[
     'width','height','url','method',
     {
          width:'100px',
          height:'100px',
          getWidth:function(){return this.width},
          getHeight:function(){return this.height}
     }
].jsonClass();

Product=[
     'width','height','url','link','method',
     Image,
     {
        method:'product-pict',
        getMethod:function(){return this.method}
     }
].jsonClass()

Mood=[
     'width','height','url','method',
     Image,
     {
        method:'mood-pict',
        getMethod:function(){return this.method}
     }
].jsonClass()

Specific=[
     'width','height','url','method',
     Image,
     {
        method:'specific-pict',
        getMethod:function(){return this.method}
     }
].jsonClass()

//Produits
var P1=new Product('100px','100px','http://dev.playboy-fragrance.fr/sites/default/files/slide1_3.png');

//Mood
var M1=new Mood('100px','100px','http://../sites/default/files/mozaic_09.jpg');
var M2=new Mood('100px','100px','http://../sites/default/files/mozaic_11.jpg');
var M3=new Mood('100px','100px','http://../sites/default/files/mozaic_20.jpg');
var M4=new Mood('100px','100px','http://../sites/default/files/mozaic_12.jpg');
var M5=new Mood('100px','100px','http://../sites/default/files/mozaic_08.jpg');

//Specific
var S1=new Specific('100px','100px','http://../sites/default/files/mozaic_09.jpg');

console.log (P1);
console.log (M1);
console.log (S1);
```

It returns

```
constr {width: "100px", height: "100px", url: "http://dev.playboy-fragrance.fr/sites/default/files/slide1_3.png", method: "product-pict", getMethod: function…}
```

How can i display it with JS ? (Java or jQuery)

Comment: I wanted to answer it, but it is so broad that none of the answers I give will answer your specific case.
I'm voting to close, and giving you some advice instead:
1. First learn what javascript is, how it can manipulate DOM; 2. Learn jQuery if you're going to do a lot of DOM manipulation. You should know what you can do with a technology, and how, before using it.
... As for this particular case, don't use `Classier Json`. Learn Javascript instead. Learn what Function.prototype is and how you can build classes based on it.

Comment: For example, to create an image element using javascript, you can call `var myImage = document.createElement('img')`, and then assign attributes to it `myImage.src='http://..../mosaic.jpg';` and then insert it where you want, for example `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(img);`